# Erro ASP.NET MVC referencia circular ao serializar objeto

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net

Boa tarde caros companheiros! Sou iniciante no ASP.NET MVC e no C#, estou desenvolvendo um projeto e encontrei um problema.

Basicamente, é um sistema de cadastro de lojas. Tenho duas tabelas, uma chamada Lojas e outra chamada Donos (Onde, obviamente, são registrados os donos das lojas).

**Aqui está um trecho do Model  Loja :**

```
    [Display(Name = "Dono")]
    [ForeignKey("Dono")]
    public int IdDono { get; set; }
    public virtual Dono Dono { get; set; }
```

**Aqui está um trecho do Model Dono :**

```
    public class Dono:BaseModel
{

    public int IdLoja { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Início")]
    public DateTime DtInicio { get; set; }

    public List<Loja> Loja { get; set; }
}
```

**E aqui está um trecho do meu LojaController:**

```
        [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Adicionar(Loja loja)
    {
        string msg = "";
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Dono dono = new Dono();
            DonoRep.Save(dono);
            lojaRep.Save(loja);

        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var item in ModelState.ToList())
            {
                foreach (var e in item.Value.Errors.ToList())
                {
                    msg += "* " + e.ErrorMessage + "<br/>";
                }
            }
        }

        return Json(new { loja = loja, msg = msg });
```

**E o meu código JavaScript:**

```
function Salvar() {
var loja = {};
$('#Loja').serializeArray().map(function (x) { loja[x.name] = x.value; });
    $.ajax({
    url: $('#Loja').attr('action'),
    type: 'POST',
    data: { loja: loja },
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.loja.Id > 0) {
            CleanForm('#Loja')
            RefreshGridView(LojaGridView);
            noty({
                text: 'salvo com sucesso.',
                layout: 'bottomRight',
                type: 'success',
                timeout: 5000
            });
        }
        else {
            noty({
                text: data.msg != '' ? data.msg : 'Não foi possível salvar, certifique-se de que o formulário foi preenchido corretamente.',
                layout: 'bottomRight',
                type: 'error',
                timeout: 7000
            });
        }
    }
});
```

}

**Então, o que acontece é o seguinte:**

Criei uma view com um form para cadastrar a loja e incluir o dono da loja. Mas sempre que eu tento salvar, eu me deparo com este erro (OB) :

**FOI DETECTADA UMA REFERENCIA CIRCULAR AO SERIALIZAR UM OBJETO DO TIPO Sistema.Models_Loja.Lojas**

Alguem pode me ajudar a esclarecer isso? Se precisarem de mais informações, é so dizer. Sou novato, então deve ser alguma coisa boba que estou deixando passar.

Comment: Pelo que pesquisei, é um erro com meu Json, mas não consegui resolver com as soluções propostas no google.

Comment: Existe alguma `Loja` sem `Dono` ou `Dono` sem `Loja`? Porque senão você tá numa sinuca de bico

Comment: Na verdade, funciona da seguinte forma:
Tenho uma tabela chamada pessoas, outra chamada Donos e outra chamada Lojas.
A tabela donos é apenas a ligação entre pessoas e lojas, neste caso, podem haver donos com várias lojas, mas nenhuma loja sem dono.
Ao cadastrar uma loja é criado um novo dono, contendo Id da tabela pessoa e Id da tabela loja

Comment: Em `Dono`, tire a propriedade `IdLoja` e altere `public List<Loja> Loja { get; set; }` para `public virtual ICollection<Loja> Lojas { get; set; }`

Comment: Testei essa solução, mas sem sucesso. Aparentemente, funcionou com  [ScriptIgnore]. Outro erro apareceu agora, mas acredito que dê para quebrar a cabeça sozinho. Obrigado mesmo assim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referências circulares são uma indicação de que seu design tem algo estranho, porém uma solução mais rápida do que refatorar o seu código é usar [[JsonIgnore]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.jsonutilities.jsonignore.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) como você mesmo mencionou nos comentário.

Comment: Procurei sobre como utilizar o [JsonIgnore] mas sem sucesso, nessa procura encontrei o  [ScriptIgnore] que aparentemente resolveu o problema..